# has_and_belongs_to_many association that acts as "through"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many, polymorphic-associations

## MODELS

### Patient:

***Description:*** 
Should have only 1 ***Referrer***

***Association:***

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :referrer
```

### Referrer:

***Description:*** 
Contains all the types of referrers such as, but is not limited to:

- Partners
- etc.

***Association:***

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :referrer
```

### Referrer Type (a new model I think I should add):

Details of referrers are here, such as *name of the website* that lead the patient to go to this hospital, or *name of the partner* that suggested the hospital to the patient.

## WORKFLOW & EXPLANATIONS

In a form, the hospital employee takes the details of the patient. One of the details is the ***referrer*** -- the entity that referred the patient to this hospital. The referrer is rendered as a **dropdown listbox**.

I made the association between Patient-Referrer as HABTM because of the following reasons:

1. The Referrer model will also be used by another model aside from Patient.
2. The Referrer model has its own scaffold where an admin can add/remove referrers.

## REQUIREMENT (THE PROBLEM)

Every time the dropdown box's value is "Partner", there should be a field to input the name of that entity. That is where the 3rd model will come in. The 3rd model will contain the:

1. name of the partner
2. a reference to the Referrer model's record named "Partner"
3. a reference to the Patient record.

With the 3rd model now in play, how will I be able to ***insert new referrer details for each patient per referrer, and making it cascadable, in a sense that when I delete the Patient, the Referrer detail will be deleted, but the Referrer will still be kept untouched, the rails way.***

Answer (score 0):

### has_and_belongs_to_many is not so great

[`has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is one the most limited relations in ActiveRecord and really only fits where you need a very simple many-to-many relationship and:

- You will never need a join model or to attach logic to the join table
- You will never need to attach any extra data to the join table
- You will never need to query the join table separately

There is no HABTM "through" because HABTM does not have a join model. Thats kind of the whole point. You cannot use polymorphism in a HABTM relationship - as that requires a join model.

Using HABTM is not the correct choice here.

[In most cases you should be using `has_many :though` instead.](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/)

Here what you want is a one to many relation with a join model:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :referral, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :referrer, through: :referral
end

class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :partner
  validates_uniqueness_of :patient_id
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
  has_many :referred_patients, through: :referrals
end
```

### [Polymorpism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

It is possible to use polymorphism to let the same associations point to different tables:

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :referred, polymorphic: :true
  belongs_to :referrer, polymorphic: :true
  validates_uniqueness_of :referred_id, scope: :referred_type
end
```

You would need to add `referred_type:string` and `referrer_type:string` columns to `referrals`.

```
# app/models/concerns/referable.rb
module Referable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :referral, as: :referred, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :referrer, through: :referral
    has_many :referrals, as: :referrer
    has_many :referred_entities, through: :referrals
                        source: :referred
  end
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Referable
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Referable
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Referable
end
```

This example would let Patient, Doctor and Partner be either the referring party or have a referral. However one big drawback is the lack of joins and eager loading for polymorphic associations since the joined table cannot be known beforehand.